# Binding Gridview with List created from JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am creating a web application in which I got JSON response from klout API.
My code is as follow,

```
var list= _jsserializer.Deserialize<List<MyItem>>(text_klout as string);
```

The definition for myItem is

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string id;
    public string displayName;
    public string name;
    public string slug;
    public string imageUrl;
}
```

I dragged a GridView in aspx page.Then I did this in code behind file

```
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

but my GridView is not populated with List Fields.
Any one who can guide me with this.
Thank you in meekness

Comment: What does the GridView look like? Is it autogenerated columns or custom bindings?

Comment: i set the autogenerated Column to false..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is perfectly Fine ,We just need to add accessor and mutators with Fields in myItems,Otherwise it will not work.Hope this will help you guys.I found it after 5 to 6 hours.